Can cyclopentylmethyl ether replace the use of methyl tert-butyl ether as an octane improvement additive
Can the replacement of methyl tert-butyl ether as an octane enhancer with cyclopentyl methyl ether be a better choice as a more eco friendly solution?
https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/CA/en/product/sial/791962?icid=sharepdp-clipboard-copy-productdetailpage#product-documentation
https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/CA/en/search/methyl-tertiary-butyl-ether?focus=products&page=1&perpage=30&sort=relevance&term=methyl%20tertiary-butyl%20ether&type=product

More eco friendly solution: switch to EV, solar, geothermal or wind powered.
